# Multiple category selection in post, shows less important category in breadcrumb

Tags: categories, breadcrumb

In my blog I followed a strategy of selecting multiple applicable categories for a post. Suppose an article about *The Last Supper by Leonardo da Vinci* can have both the categories "Painting" and "Religion", and if the article has a brief profile about Mr. Leonardo da Vinci, then I will also assign another category to the post: "Artists' Profile". (No sub-category, all are parents)

But when the concern is of sorting the posts by category, I'd surely gonna sort it by the category "Painting", because to me, *Painting* is the right category if I want to pose the article in a single category. So I'd love to show the breadcrumb like:

> Home  » Painting » The Last Supper
>   by Leonardo da Vinci

But with the plugin Breadcrumb NavXT, I can't assign my breadcrumb as my wish. It's just taking the category in ascending order, so the breadcrumb for post shows:

> Home » Artists' Profile » The Last Supper by Leonardo da Vinci

Because the post takes categories in ascending order as:

- Artists' Profile
- Painting
- Religion

So...
How can I be able to let the breadcrumb understand me, or assign a post to a single category only for breadcrumb?

Comment: I did something like this, but for rewriting the permalink. Basically, I added a meta-box with radio buttons to choose the main category, then modify the `rewrite_rules` to change permalink accordingly. If you share the code for generating your breadcrumb, I could try to adapt my code for your case.

Comment: :) I'm afraid, I've already mentioned that I'm using a plugin: "But with the plugin _Breadcrumb NavXT_, I can't assign my breadcrumb." Waiting for your answer patiently. Thanks in advance.